# Binding data MVVM after Tap on ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is my situation: 
- I have a WebApi that sends me a json data.
- My app reads this data and binds all information in a list box
- When I tap on Item of the list box I want to show all information about that item

The problem is: How can I bind data on the new view?
This is the code after tap (MainViewModel):

```
this.ProfessorDetail = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
if (SelectedIndexProfessors != -1)
    {
         //This variable contain all detail information
         Professor x = Professors.ElementAt(SelectedIndexProfessors);
         //Open new page
         App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/ProfessorDetailPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never made a page based application, but I was looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) link and from basic knowledge of WPF, I do know you need to set the `DataContext` of that page just like you asked.

Take a look at the following code in the link:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage2), tb1.Text);
```

That is sending the text entered in `tb1` to the object you're navigating to.  Then look at how the receiving object is utilizing that information:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.NavigationParameter as string;
    ....
}
```

You're going to want to follow the same idea, except you're going to want to do something like:

```
App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(".....", ...), x);
```

And then in the page itself, you're going to want to set up a LoadState event in `ProfessorDetailPage` control and inside it do:

```
Professor prof = x as Professor;
if( prof != null)
{
    this.DataContext = prof;
}
```

That should set the `DataContext` of `ProfessorDetailPage` and your data should be populated.

Let me know how it works out, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Uri` parameter to pass simple string information between pages. For example, in your `RelayCommand` pass unique information about selected professor :

```
.........
//pass selected professor Id to ProfessorDetailPage
App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/ProfessorDetailPage.xaml?professorId=" + x.ProfessorId, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
.........
```

Then in the `ProfessorDetailPage`'s `Loaded` or `NavigatedTo` event handler get the uri parameter and display information accordingly :

```
.........
string professorId;
if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("professorId", out professorId))
{  
    //load information based on professorId parameter value
}
.........
```

Comment: This answer didn't show up until I posted my answer, weird.  But this looks valid too! +1.  I'm unsure, but a potential downside would be that you can't set the entire DataContext of the control this way unless you can do `?DataContext=` and pass the object.  Would be interested in finding out if you can!